# Using MEF, how to restrict the plugin to access classes outside it?

Tags: c#, wpf, mef

Using MEF, we do have a WPF application, with plugins as `UserControl` controls. 
The main window contains a `TabControl` with every tab representing a separate plugin.

```
// IPlugin : UserControl
var myPlugin = new IPlugin(); 
var mainTabControl = new TabControl();
var myTabItem = new TabItem();

myTabItem.Content = myPlugin;
mainTabControl.Items.Add(myTabItem);
```

The problem is I do have some actions that I would like to restrict from the plugin side, like closing the Main window.
For example:

```
[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
public partial class UserControl1 : IPlugin, UserControl {
    // ...
    var mainWindow = Window.GetWindow( this );
    mainWindow.Close();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, how would you prevent Environment.Exit(0)?

Comment: It's not necessary about exiting the application. I just don't understand how to properly set up the permissions for the plugin. Especially from the security point of view.

Comment: You most likely going to need to add mef metadata and make your import lazy to get the metadata.  You can then examine the metadata to know if the plug in should load.